# Coded UI Test Project calling from ASP.net Application

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Scope : Customize the Coded UI Test Project

Requirement : Coded UI Test project is directly open my ASP.net application.

Open the CodedUITestBuilder recording toolbar when i click on button in my application.
I want to open CodedUITestBuilder from  my application via Coded UI Test project.

I tried but not found feasible solution.I am expecting your positive reply.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The Coded UI Test Builder is a tool that is only available within VS 2010 + Premium or Ultimate.  The only way to access it would be to do so within a fully licensed Visual Studio instance, so including the technology within your application isn't possible.

This might help you accomplish your end-goal:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/63e71f9e-f318-45bc-9d92-261312d90467/is-there-an-api-or-sdk-for-codedui-test-builder?forum=vsautotest